# Using WaitGroup and channels in Go

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

I'm working on a freight service using Go that call many webservices, but I'm not sure how can I implement the concurrency model. This aproach just worked, but sometimes it locks. I believe there are some issue with channels and WaitGroup. I realy need to use WaitGroups or only the channels are enouth to routines lock.

```
// Call carriers quote webservice
var wg sync.WaitGroup
error := make(chan error)
quote := make(chan []freight.Quote)
for _, c := range carriers {
    go c.Quote(&wg, obj, quote, error)
}
wg.Wait()

// Collect the results
quotes:= make([]freight.Quote, 0)
for i := 1; i < len(carriers); i++ {
    err := <-error
    quoteAws:= <-quote

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    if quoteAws != nil {
        quotes= append(quotes, quoteAws...)
    }
}
close(error)
close(quote)

func (carrier CarrierA) Quote(wg *sync.WaitGroup, obj Volume, quotes chan []Quote, err chan error) 
{
    // Deal with waitgroup
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    
    // Quote the freigth
    err <- nil
    quotes <- quotesResult
    return
}
```

Comment: There's no such thing as "the best concurrency model". There are always trade-offs.  What problem do you need help solving?

Comment: Hi @Flimzy, I'm starting with concurrency in go, and I don't known if I'm doing it right. Or if there are some caveats on my approach that I'm not noticed.

Comment: Is your code working as intended?

Comment: @Flimzy sometime it works, sometime locks. I'm thinking to remove the WaitGroup, I believe that the channels will do the sync/wait job.

Comment: A lot is wrong here, e.g. you must wg.Add outside of the goroutine.

Comment: So the answer is "No, it does not work as intended." Please update your question to ask an actual question. Focus on one of the problems you're facing, and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use slices to collect the errors and quotes. Use a wait group to wait for the goroutines to complete.

```
errs := make([]error, len(carriers))
quotes := make([]freight.Quote, len(carriers))
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i, c := range carriers {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int, c Carrier) {
        defer wg.Done()
        quotes[i], errs[i] = c.Quote(args)
    }(i, c)
}
wg.Wait()
```